# get index out of selected elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexing

So I have a div with some child elements and when I select one with jQuery I want to get the index of it within a selector

```
<div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

So lets say that I have the last element in the main div selected. If I call index() on it it will give me '7' because out of all the child elements the index is '7'. But now lets say I want to get the index based on the other 'red' elements, the goal is to return a value of '4' because out of all of the 'red' elements it is the fifth one. I looked through the documentation and didnt find a whole lot, then I experimented with putting selectors in the index() method like index('.red') but I couldn't get anything working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/index/) says:

> **`.index( element )`**
>   **element** The DOM element or first element within the jQuery object to look for.

So can do:

```
selectedElements.filter('.red').index(this);
```

If you don't have `selectedElements` already, you can select corresponding siblings with, for example:

```
$(this).parent().children('.red')
```

If every element has only one class and then the filter can be dynamic:

```
var index = $(this).parent().children('.' + this.className).index(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info instead of using $(this).index() I did $(this).parent().children('.red').index(this) and it solved it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.index()` function documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

For the above if one wants to get the index of a element of the red class use `$('div .red').index(elem);`

`$('div .red)` will create a list of the elements with the red class within the div. `.index(elem)` will search for the `elem` within the array.

Answer (score 1):

Running through all of them using id=test as parent

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/T7fXR/

```
$('#test > div').each(function(){
    var thisClass=$(this).attr('class');
    $(this).css('background',thisClass );
    /* get index based on class*/
    var idx=$('.'+thisClass).index(this);
    $(this).text('Index= '+idx)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works just fine with your given HTML:

```
$('div').eq(5)​​​​​​​​​​.index('.red') // 3
```

You can place selectors into the `.index()` function.